Так может - запятая после "так" нужна?
Нужна ли запятая после слова "так" в предложении:

Так может, начнем заполнение пробелов с этого места?


Правильно:
Так, может, начнем заполнение пробелов с этого места?
Пояснение
Может — вводное слово, так — наречие в значении "в таком случае, тогда".
ТАК. I. местоим. нареч. 7. В таком случае, тогда. Не хочешь 
слушать - т. уйди. Отвечать — т. отвечать. Взялся за работу 
— т. закончи. Обещал — т. выполняй.

Карта слов
Так, может, не стоит поддаваться такому мифу, а опровергнуть его?
